# How can I access data from a container view from the parent view controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I have a view controller(`SignUpController`) and it has 1 image view at the top, 2 buttons at the bottom and 1 view as `container view`. The  Container view(`InfoRegisterController`) contains `scrollview` with several text fields. Container view doesn’t contain any buttons. So, now i need to access text fields of Container view in the parent view controller (or can say as : I need to access all data from container view to parent view controller) so that I can register the user by clicking Register button at the bottom in `SignUpController`. I couldn’t solve it through delegates and `NSUserDefaults` too. So , Please help me to solve this in swift 4 ?

This is the parent view controller:

```
import UIKit
import Material

class SignUpController: UIViewController {  


@IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var register: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    backgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    backgroundView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    register.layer.cornerRadius = 5 

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated) // No need for semicolon

    let tv: InfoRegisterController = self.childViewControllers[0] as!InfoRegisterController

    print("Hello")
     //tv.viewWillAppear(true) 
 }
```

All data must be accessed to this place so that I can post it to server.

```
@IBAction func Register(_ sender: Any) {




    }
} // class end
```

Container View:

```
import UIKit
import Material

class InfoRegisterController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,  UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var fullName: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Email: ErrorTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Password: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var verifyPassword: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var address: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var permanentAddress: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var currentAddress: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var DOB: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var occupation: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var selectGender: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var identificationType: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var identificationID: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var issuedDate: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var issuedDistrict: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var licenseNumber: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fathersName: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var grandfathersName: TextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mobileNumber: TextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.fullName.delegate = self
    self.Email.delegate = self
    self.Password.delegate = self
    self.verifyPassword.delegate = self
    self.address.delegate = self
    self.permanentAddress.delegate = self
    self.currentAddress.delegate = self
    self.DOB.delegate = self
    self.occupation.delegate = self
    self.identificationID.delegate = self
    self.issuedDate.delegate = self
    self.issuedDistrict.delegate = self
    self.licenseNumber.delegate = self
    self.fathersName.delegate = self
    self.grandfathersName.delegate = self
    self.mobileNumber.delegate = self

    }  
}
```

Here, I need to access all fields fullName,Email, Password,verifyPassword,address, permanentAddress,currentAddress, DOB,occupation and all others to SignUpController so that I can register new user.

Comment: @Swifty guy why you need a different controller class for text fields, wh not just do it in SignUpController?

Comment: try to use tv.fullname, tv.Email, not sure just check it i think you get access those properties.

Comment: Because I needed a scroll view for many fields of middle only. @Tushar Sharma

Comment: It didn't work. Although it takes but doesn't show any values. @ Morshed Alam

Comment: @Swiftguy kindly check my answer if it works for you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To gain access to the container view from your parent, you will have to pass a reference from the container view to the parent and then use it in the parent view controller, there are many ways to do that and here is one of them.

In your `viewDidAppear` of `InfoRegisterController` which is the container view controller add the following code, this method will get a reference of `InfoRegisterController` into the parent to be used.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let signUpControllerParent = self.parent as! SignUpController
    signUpControllerParent.saveContrainerViewRefference(vc: self)

}
```

Now in `SignUpController` add a local variable for the coming reference to be saved and used later to get the data from the textfields.

```
var infoRegisterRefferenceVC : InfoRegisterController?
```

Add this method also in your parent `SignUpController`

```
func saveContrainerViewRefference(vc:InfoRegisterController){

    self.infoRegisterRefferenceVC = vc

}
```

Now you can have access to all the textfields and the methods in the container view from the parent for example:

```
var fullNameTextField = self.infoRegisterRefferenceVC.fullName.text
```

This should be it :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this. You can use "Delegate" and "Protocol" or `prepareForSegue` method in parent view controller.

```
var somePropertyYouWantToAccess: NSString?
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

  if segue.identifier == "yourChildViewSegueIdentifier" {
       let childVc = segue.destinationViewController as ContainerViewController
        self.somePropertyYouWantToAccess = childVc.firstName
    }
}
```