# UIPageViewController setViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to implement a PageViewController that switches to a different ViewController when a button is pressed. I can successfully load each "child" ViewController using the setViewControllers method during viewDidLoad().

However when I call the setViewControllers method outside viewDidLoad(), it does not change the current "child" ViewController.

Can you call the method setViewControllers at any point or just once during viewDidLoad()? Also is there a way to change a variable in the pageviewcontrollers dataSource extensions?

My project consists of a entry ViewController with a "Settings" button and a ContainerView. Inside the ContainerView I have the UIPageViewController.

Code for PageViewController:

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {
var slides = [SlideItem]()
var currentIndex: Int!

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    initSlides()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let viewController = viewSlideViewController(currentIndex ?? 0){
        let viewControllers = [viewController]

        setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func viewSlideViewController(_ index: Int) -> SlideViewController? {

    guard let storyboard = storyboard,
    let page = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SlideViewController") as? SlideViewController else {
        return nil
    }

    page.slide = slides[index]
    page.slideIndex = index

    return page

}

func viewSettingsViewController(_ index: Int) -> SettingsViewController? {

    guard let storyboard = storyboard,
        let page = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as? SettingsViewController else {
            return nil
    }
    return page

}

func initSlides(){

    slides.append(SlideItem.init(filename: "Slide 1", comparison: false, highYield: false, videoURL: nil,
                                 groupOrganSystem: ["A"],
                                 groupMedicalSpecialty: ["B"]))
    slides.append(SlideItem.init(filename: "Slide 2", comparison: false, highYield: false, videoURL: nil,
                                 groupOrganSystem: ["A"],
                                 groupMedicalSpecialty: ["B"]))
}

func sidebarCommands(button: String, state: Bool){
    switch button {
        case "settings":
            self.setViewControllers([viewSettingsViewController(0)!], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
            print("settings")
    default:
        return
    }
}

}
```

Extensions:

```
extension PageViewController : UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let viewController = viewController as? SlideViewController,
        let index = viewController.slideIndex,
        index > 0 {
        return viewSlideViewController(index - 1)
    }
    return nil
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let viewController = viewController as? SlideViewController,
        let index = viewController.slideIndex,
        (index + 1) < slides.count {
        return viewSlideViewController(index + 1)
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I figured out what I was doing wrong. I didn't have the right reference for the active PageViewController in the ContainerView.

So of course called the setViewControllers function on random PageViewController did not produce the correct results.

[I found this answer explains how to correctly get a reference from a ContainerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442169/6364860)

Comment: I think I have a similar issue. Could you explain your solution a bit more?

Comment: In order to access the containerview from the parent viewcontroller, you need to have a reference to it. I followed the answer in the link i posed so the child vc sends a reference to the parent vc during its viewDidAppear method

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIPageviewController in this way: (inheritance)
https://medium.com/how-to-swift/how-to-create-a-uipageviewcontroller-a948047fb6af

Answer (score 0):

You can call `setViewControllers` at any point (I've been doing that).

The fact that it does not produce expected results is probably a result of bug in your code, include your code if you want to help out with that.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I added my code above. Could a problem be because the UIPageViewController is located inside a ContainerView?

Comment: @donny.rewq where else do you call it?

Comment: I use a embed segue

Comment: @donny.rewq you need to call setViewControllers explicitly, I wanted to see that

Comment: @donny.rewq which one is not working? they both seem correct

Comment: If i load one at a time in viewDidLoad, then the correct one shows up. But when i try to load the other one from my sidebarCommands  function, it does not load. Nothing happends

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163668/discussion-between-milan-nosa-and-donny-rewq).